# How can I write this subquery with 2 tables in Linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, subquery, entity-framework-core

```
SELECT 
    S.Name, Result.Id, Longitud, Latitud, Trandate, EndTrandate, 
    Salesman, TranId, ClientId, TranType, TranStatus, Result.Division_Id, 
    UniqueTransactionId, Result.RecordId
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Salesman ORDER BY EndTranDate DESC) AS RowNum,
         Id, Longitud, Latitud, Trandate, EndTrandate, Salesman, TranId, 
         ClientId, TranType, TranStatus, Division_Id, UniqueTransactionId, 
         RecordId
     FROM 
         LocationHistory) AS Result
INNER JOIN
    Salesman S ON Result.Salesman = S.Id
WHERE 
    Result.RowNum = 1 
ORDER BY 
    Salesman
```

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might prove helpful.

Comment: @NetMage I doubt it would - your "recipe" is too generic and does not take into account EF Core specifics. At the same time itl does not cover SQL features not supported by LINQ like `OVER` and `PARTITION` clauses of the OP query which simply have no LINQ translation except the query provider supports custom extensions for that .

Comment: @IvanStoev I am reluctant to add simulations for some of those as I think it becomes too complicated to be a recipe...